# dataGridView scroll move up and down

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have problem in my application and I hope to find the solution.

I have tow dataGridView (dataGridView1, dataGridView2).
dataGridView2 depend on dataGridView1; when I select the #2 row in dataGridView 1 the dataGridView2 will automatically select the #2 row.

But the problem happened when I have a large number of rows in dataGridView2 the scroll bar of dataGridView2 does not move down with selected row. So I cannot see the select row in dataGridView2.

How can I programmatically make the dataGridView2 scroll move up and down with selected row in dataGridView1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` is the property you are looking for.